# Can I set a password on a collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm a mongodb newbie and was wondering if I can set different usernames and passwords on a collection -- not just on a database?

Some users will have access to all the collections in the db, some to just a select few...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from 2.6 onward yes you can grant individual users access at the collection level http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/